# Как получить data attr к datalist(option)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вывожу список так

```
<label>Привилегии: <input type="text" name="status" list="status" id="status-add">
            <datalist id="status">
                <option value="text" data-id="1"></option>
            </datalist>
          </label>
```

нужно получить data id выбранной опции. Важно, значение в поле value могут дублироваться, но айди будут разные. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://github.com/b3n/datalist/blob/master/src/datalist.js

Comment: эммм, это что?)

Comment: Это для jquery реализация `datalist`, который вы сможете использовать, для своих `datalist`'ов.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name="status"]').on('focusout', function() {
  let v, id;
  if (v = $(this).val()) {
    id = $('#status option[value=' + v + ']').data('id');
    console.clear();
    console.log(id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Привилегии: 
    <input type="text" name="status" list="status" id="status-add">
    <datalist id="status">
        <option value="text" data-id="1"></option>
        <option value="mext" data-id="2"></option>
        <option value="pext" data-id="3"></option>
    </datalist>
</label>
<input type="button" value="go"/>
```